# named-checkzone: chroot option "-t" as non-root user

Tags: linux, dns, bind

We have bind nameservers running in chroot environment. We edit zone files on a different host where we want to verify them using `named-checkzone` before uploading. We used parameter `-w` to adjust the directories, but this stopped working when we started to use includes in the zone files with an absolute path. So I tried parameter `-t` instead to emulate the chroot behaviour of the actual server, but to implement this `named-checkzone` needed privileges to chroot. I was considering creating a copy of named-checkzone and giving it CAP_SYS_CHROOT capability to avoid the need to run it as root. The copy would then be made executable for the group of users tasked with editing zone files.

Since CAP_SYS_CHROOT can lead to security problems (like "create own etc/passwd, chroot + su"), I would prefer to avoid it. Is there a better way to get `named-checkzone` work in this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a privileged script or service that sets up the chroot and runs an unprivileged `named-checkzone` inside (i.e. dropping privileges to the original UID after chroot). That's how BIND itself and other network services implement their "chroot" options.

Alternatively, create an unprivileged *user namespace* with `unshare --user`, in which you'll be able to set up custom mount namespaces – UID 0 inside a user namespace has is not automatically mapped to UID 0 in the parent namespace and has no special privileges there. (User namespaces are commonly used as part of container implementations.)

(Or, finally, do not use absolute paths...)

Comment: Ok, I guess I have to use a binary wrapper since capabilities on scripts don't seem to work (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87348/capabilities-for-a-script-on-linux)